# VBScript - How to Generate a Random Number, then an If-Statement to Use this Number to Pick an Option

Tags: if-statement, random, vbscript, compilation

I would like to know how to, (In VBScript) generate a random number that would not be the same on a different computer, and then use that number and perhaps some If-Statements so that one of 10 possible options can be activated, eg.

```
If (A random number between 1 - 10, eg. 2) then (Continue on part of script then wscript.quit)
Else if (A different number, eg. 7) then (continue on to different part of script then wscript.quit)
```

etc.

So that I would have 10 different options for the script to choose randomly.

Is this possible? If so then would someone be able to compile an example of this so I can put my own script in and use it? 
Thanks to any answers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need `randomize` and `rnd`.
`int(rnd * n) + 1` evaluates to an integer number between 1 and n.
And you might use `select case...` here as well, try this:

```
dim r
randomize
r = int(rnd*10) + 1
select case r
    case 2
        '... 

    case 7
        '... 

end select
```

Answer (score 8):

And If you would rand from min to max:

```
Dim max,min,rand
max=54
min=23
Randomize
rand = Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min)
WScript.Echo rand
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Dim i

For i=1 to 5

Randomize

a=Rnd
b=a+1

msgbox b

Next
```

Comment: Don't need to call `Randomize()` every iteration of the loop, you will likely make the process less random.